# Read-only property as Key in EF Core 2

Tags: entity-framework

I would like EF Core 2 to accept a read-only property as Key. Consider the following model:

```
public class Session
{
    public string Key => $"{ClientDomain}:{SessionId}";

    public string ClientDomain { get; private set; }

    public string SessionId { get; private set; }
}
```

Fluent mapping code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().HasKey(e => e.Key);
```

When attempting to add a migration, an error reads: "No backing field could be found for property 'Key' of entity type 'Session' and the property does not have a setter."

How can I achieve this kind of mapping in EF Core 2, preferably without having to change the model class just for the sake of EF?

Comment: EF must have write access to the key property (or, in ef-core 3, at least the backing field) because it needs to set it when materializing entities. Doing it your way would impose too many constraints on the order in which properties can be set and the entity key can be set in the change tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Key` property returns unique value based on `ClientDomain` and `SessionId` then it seems reasonable to create composite primary key

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Session>()
    .HasKey(s => new { s.ClientDomain, s.SessionId });
```